# How to say “pen and paper roleplay game”?

Tags: translation

Is it something at least some people know, or must I assume they will misunderstand “roleplay game” as something fishy with sexual connotations?

I mean something like Dungeons and Dragons and other [pen and paper games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabletop_role-playing_game). Wikipedia translates it as “桌上角色扮演遊戲”, but I get the impression nobody understands this or it is being misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

桌上角色扮演，or in jargon among players: 跑团。

P.S. It seems that other answerers don't know the term 跑团游戏, which amazes me.

Edit:

The etymology of 『跑团』is unknown to me, but I guess it's because "a group of people playing (running) in the virtual world".

Comment: Any guesses how 跑團（running group?) comes to mean this?

Comment: @Ludi I don't know... But see my edit.

Comment: @Ludi random internet source: https://www.zhihu.com/question/300850476 跑團 is explained as a group of people running a campaign or adventure, 跑 is a mistranslation of English “Run” (running a program)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler expression for 桌上角色扮演游戏 would probably be: 角色扮演桌游.

Comment: Will this be understood by Chinese speakers? Does it carry risk of being interpreted as inappropriate adult stuff?

Comment: No not at all. You can have a look through this thread: https://www.zhihu.com/question/301994814

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no specific expression “桌上角色扮演游戏”. People more likely to use "桌游” , which means play on the table, most of the time with cards. If you want to emphasis it is a roleplay game, you'd better describe as "角色扮演类桌游”. The “角色扮演类” is it's attribute.